# Cannot login to the Ubuntu Store

Tags: vlc, snap

I cannot login to the Ubuntu Store using my credentials. I have already reset the password 3 times and still, the store prompts me, "Invalid username or password."

I can login to the single sign on portal properly.

I am trying to install VLC as a snap package.What can I be missing here? Should I configure anything before doing such?

Thanks,

Comment: I heard about that bug and thought it should be solved by now. I was wrong or it is corrected but you're missing updates.

Comment: My system is up to date. I emailed them and they said that there is currently an issue with logging in to the Ubuntu Store on 16.04. They said I could just use the command line installation for now and that's just what I did recently. Thanks.

Comment: So the bug isn't solved. Pity, because AFAIK the main reason for adopting the gnome-software (rebranded, of course) instead of the old in-house solution was precisely the support for snap and that bug defeats that purpose completely (for the moment).